# How to get spell information in items by Blizaard API?

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I can get a node "itemSpells" by the item api.
But if i want to get the detail information, how i can get it?
Just like :
    "itemSpells": [

```
    {
        "spellId": 109848,
        "spell": 
        {
            "id": 109848,
            "name": "Item - Dragon Soul - Proc - Int Spirit Mace 1H LFR",
            "icon": "spell_holy_avenginewrath",
            "description": ""
        },
        "nCharges": 0,
        "consumable": false,
        "categoryId": 0,
        "trigger": "ON_EQUIP"
    }],
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wowpedia.org/World_of_Warcraft_API#Spell_Functions

Are you looking for GetSpellInfo() ?